# preprocessor definition / add a new profile

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have two profile in my project, (debug and release) I want to add a new profile (debug2) and use sth like this:

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
    // func1();
#elif defined(RELEASE)
    // func2();
#elif defined(DEBUG2)
    // func3();
#endif
```

but the problem is when I add a new profile and I try to build the program as debug2 `func3();` is disable

Is there sth that I should do in `c/c++ -> preprocessor -> preprocessor definition`  ?

Comment: Yes, just add DEBUG2 in the preprocessor definition, for only the debug2 configuration.

Comment: would you please write exactly what I should be in `preprocessor definition` for debug, release and debug2 ...

Comment: That may depend on the VS version you are using, anyway usually you should find _DEBUG among the preprocessor definitions for Debug, NDEBUG for Release... If you define a new "debug2" configuration, just change those to DEBUG2 or whatever fits to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may depend on the VS version you are using, anyway usually you should find:   `_DEBUG` among the preprocessor definitions for Debug configuration,
`NDEBUG` for Release configuration.

If you define a new "debug2" configuration, just change those to DEBUG2 or whatever fits to you.